# python celery retry countdown

Tags: python, celery, countdown

Ситуация:

У меня работает одновременно порядка 100 задач. И в одной из них происходит ошибка, и я через `function.retry(countdown=30)` пытаюсь запустить заново таску через 30 секунд. Но через 30 секунд у меня все еще работают другие задачи.

Вопрос:

Перезапущенная таска запустится ровно через 30 секунд, в обход других задач. Или же запуститься когда очередь освободится?

Если запуститься когда очередь освободится, есть ли способ явно заставить таску запустится поверх других?